# Java: Help with a RegEx

Tags: java, regex

So, I want to replace all `&` in the following string with a single `&`.  These `&` can be separated by one or more `space`s.  I have a sample input string and a code snippet of what I have.

**Input string:**

```
a&   &    &&&  & b
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
String foo = "a&   &    &&& & b".replaceAll("(\\s*&+\\s*&\\s*)", "&");
System.out.println(foo); // prints: "a&&b"
                         // expected: "a&b"
```

I'm not sure why two `&` are ending up in the result.

Any hlep would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:`String foo = "a&   &    &&& & b".replaceAll("(\\s*&[\\s&]*)", "&");`

Answer (score 3):

why make it more complicated than it needs to be

```
"(\\s*&)+\\s*"
```

one or more (sequences of `&` preceded by zero or more whitespace) followed by zero or more whitespace